# Get all IDs of repeated rows in dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` that has duplicated rows. I want to store the IDs of the unique rows, so that each has a list of integers (the IDs where they appear in the dataframe) associated.

Let me show an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
m = ['a','b']
M = ['X','Y']
n = np.arange(3)
size = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'m': np.random.choice(m, size=size, replace=True),
                   'M': np.random.choice(M, size=size, replace=True),
                   'n': np.random.choice(n, size=size, replace=True)})
```

This generates the following dataframe:

```
   m  M  n
0  a  Y  2
1  b  X  2
2  b  X  0
3  a  Y  1
4  b  X  1
5  b  X  1
6  b  X  1
7  b  X  0
8  b  X  1
9  b  Y  0
```

I believe I want to do something like `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()`, but instead of getting the number of appearances, I want to get the *positions* where they appear. So, in this case, the desired output would be (in a dictionary form for example):

```
output = {('a','Y',1):[3],
          ('a','Y',2):[0],
          ('b','X',0):[2,7],
          ('b','X',1):[4,5,6,8],
          ('b','X',2):[1],
          ('b','Y',0):[9]
          }
```

How can I do this? The idea is to do it as efficient as possible, because the dataframe can have several columns and many thousands (or even a few million) of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `groups`

```
df.groupby(list(df)).groups
Out[176]: 
{('a', 'Y', 1): Int64Index([3], dtype='int64'),
 ('a', 'Y', 2): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 ('b', 'X', 0): Int64Index([2, 7], dtype='int64'),
 ('b', 'X', 1): Int64Index([4, 5, 6, 8], dtype='int64'),
 ('b', 'X', 2): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 ('b', 'Y', 0): Int64Index([9], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: Well, that was fast (and accurate)! Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes when the site allows me.